# Will search engines read API calls made in $(document).ready() or body load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, seo

I am designing a site and we are essentially creating an html page factory. Our database has what will comprise the static content of the page but said pages will be augmented by API calls to publicly accessible 3rd party sites. For example YouTube, Discogs, Wiki API, Last.FM all have APIs they market to webmasters.

The calls made to these APIs will be as a direct result of the static content on the page and will serve to automatically augment these pages with the most up to date from said APIs. The big question of the hour is when the page loads and these calls are made will Google, Bing, Yahoo etc. detect the API results placed in the DOM or only see the static content?

Further, would you suggest the best place to make these calls javascript/jquery eventwise in the page lifecycle, specifically  or $(doc).ready() if it makes a difference.

I saw a few other posts but they all seemed to assume the ajax would be driven by user interaction or query parameters. Our design will use the actual static page name to make the API calls on some flavor of the load process. Thanks very much.

Comment: It won't matter if it's AJAX or simple JS to modify the DOM, unless the spider executes JavaScript the content will not be visible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking search engines do not execute JavaScript so this content will be invisible to them. (They do read and execute basic JavaScript but Ajax is not basic).

The only exception to this is [Google's crawlable Ajax](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) proposal. Keep in mind that this only works for Google so every other search engine will not be able to reach your Ajax powered content if you were to do this.